# Upgrading from Java 8 to Java 11

Tags: java

At Run-time getting below error.

```
2019-02-22 05:47:19,666 [Timer-0] WARN  org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory- Initial attempt to create application context was unsuccessful.
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.wsdl.WSDLManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusApplicationContext.<init>(BusApplicationContext.java:91)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createApplicationContext(SpringBusFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:93)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:86)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:64)
        at org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.SpringBusFactory.createBus(SpringBusFactory.java:53)
        at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:90)
        at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:137)
        at org.apache.cxf.BusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus(BusFactory.java:122)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:64)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
        at com.syniverse.dre.bell.ehdp.ldap.ldap.services.LdapGatewayServiceImplService.<init>(LdapGatewayServiceImplService.java:45)
        at com.syniverse.dre.bell.ehdp.util.RedundantLdapWebServiceClient.getWsInstanceLdapGW(RedundantLdapWebServiceClient.java:65)
        at com.syniverse.dre.bell.ehdp.util.ReduntantLdapInvoker.invokeAvailableWs(ReduntantLdapInvoker.java:37)
        at com.syniverse.dre.bell.ehdp.batch.ProvisionProcess.getLDAPInfoOfSubscriber(ProvisionProcess.java:978)
        at com.syniverse.dre.bell.ehdp.batch.ProvisionProcess.run(ProvisionProcess.java:127)
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:556)
        at java.base/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:115)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:224)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:61)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:129)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:81)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:152)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:89)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:456)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1136)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:202)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:128)
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:277)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.JAXBExtensionHelper.createJAXBContext(JAXBExtensionHelper.java:196)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.JAXBExtensionHelper.getJAXBContext(JAXBExtensionHelper.java:183)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.JAXBExtensionHelper.addExtensions(JAXBExtensionHelper.java:168)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.JAXBExtensionHelper.addExtensions(JAXBExtensionHelper.java:88)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.registerInitialExtensions(WSDLManagerImpl.java:263)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.registerInitialExtensions(WSDLManagerImpl.java:243)
        at org.apache.cxf.wsdl11.WSDLManagerImpl.<init>(WSDLManagerImpl.java:113)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.activation.DataSource
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52921879/migration-to-jdk-11-has-error-occure-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-acti

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493613/what-is-the-replacement-for-javax-activation-package-in-java-9